# R Shiny dplyr reactive filters

Tags: r, filter, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I'm trying to set up a dashboard where the user can filter data by year, status, and product. Ideally it should run where each product has 2 variables associated, a satisfaction score and an importance score.When filtering from the data set, a summary mean should be calculated for the various segments the user is interested in. Then the mean importance and mean satisfaction scores are combined into a data.frame and plotted on a single plot.

Here is where I'm at...

My UI

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Membership Satisfaction"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Demographics Dashboard", tabName = "demos", icon = 
               icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

     tabItem(tabName = "demos",
             sidebarPanel(
                checkboxGroupInput("inpt","Select variables to plot", 
               choices = 
                                 c("Web" = 1,"Huddle" = 3, "Other" = 5, 
               "Test" = 7)),
            checkboxGroupInput("role", 
                               "Select Primary Role of Interest", 
                               choices = c("Student" = 1, "Not" = 2)),
            checkboxGroupInput("range", 
                               "Select year(S) of Interest", 
                               choices = c("2016"=2,"July 2017"=1))),
          fluidPage(

            plotOutput("plot")

          )))))
```

And my Server:

```
  server <- function(input,output){

  library(tidyverse)


  x <- reactive({
    inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
    role <- as.double(input$role)
    range <- as.double(input$range)

    GapAnalysis_LongFormB %>%
      filter(Product %in% inpt,
         status %in% role,
         year %in% range) %>%
       summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        pull(-1)
        })


  y <- reactive({
    inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)+1
    role <- as.double(input$role)
    range <- as.double(input$range)

 GapAnalysis_LongFormB %>%
    filter(Product %in% inpt,
         status %in% role,
         year %in% range) %>% 
   summarize(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
   pull(-1)
  })

 xyCoords<- reactive({
   x <- x()
   y <- y()

   data.frame(col1=x, col2=y)
   })



  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    xyCoords <- xyCoords()    

    xyCoords %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
     geom_point(colour ="green", shape = 17, size = 5 )+
     labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") +
     xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5) +
     geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + 
     geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)
    })

}



shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here are the variable structures:

```
> dput(head(GapAnalysis_LongFormB))
structure(list(status = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5), year = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Score = c(2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4
)), .Names = c("status", "year", "Product", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It works - only not doing exactly what I need it to. Currently, it requires an input in all 3 checkbox input variables (inpt, role, range) before it plots. I need it to require a product, but plot for each additional input. Meaning, if they select Web, it will plot the mean of web. If they select Web and year 2017, it will plot the mean of Web in 2017.

Any help is VERY appreciated!!!!

Comment: I didn't run the code, but look at `as.integer(input$inpt+1)`.  Shouldn't that be `as.integer(input$inpt) + 1`

Comment: I think they both yield the same result (in the very least nothing changed when I ran the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Changes

There were a few things here that I think are causing some trouble:

First, you are using `input$range` although you have never defined `input$range`.  You have defined a `input$yrs`, so I changed it to `input$range`.

Next, you are using `==` with `filter`, when you should be using `%in%` instead.  This allows for multiple selections, not just a single selection.  If you only want a single selection, use `radioButtons()` instead of `checkboxGroupInput()`.

In your `summarize`, you are using an additional and unnecessary subsetting. We've already used the exact same `filter` on the dataset, so no need to apply the subsetting within `summarize`.

Finally, I think you might run into some serious issues with your `xyCoords`.  Because you are using different filters on your two datasets, you likely will end up with varying vector lengths for `x` and `y`.  This will cause problems.  My suggestion is that you somehow combine the two datasets with a `full_join` to make sure `x` and `y` will always be the same length.  That's less of a question about `shiny` and more about `dplyr` as well.

I also changed some of your `reactive` objects.

### UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Membership Satisfaction"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Demographics Dashboard", tabName = "demos", icon = 
                 icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "demos",
              sidebarPanel(
                checkboxGroupInput("inpt","Select variables to plot", choices = 
                                     c("Web" = 1,"Huddle" = 3, "Other" = 5, "Test" = 7)),
                checkboxGroupInput("role", 
                                   "Select Primary Role of Interest", 
                                   choices = c("Student" = 1, "Not" = 2)),
                checkboxGroupInput("range", 
                                   "Select year(S) of Interest", 
                                   choices = c("2016"=2,"July 2017"=1))),
              fluidPage(

                plotOutput("plot")

              )))))
```

### Server:

```
server <- function(input,output){

  library(tidyverse)

  GapAnalysis_LongFormImpt <- structure(list(status = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5), year = c(1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                    1, 1, 1), Product = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                        "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Score = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1
                                                                                                                                                        )), .Names = c("status", "year", "Product", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            6L), class = "data.frame")


  GapAnalysis_LongFormSat <- structure(list(status = c(5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1), year = c(1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                   1, 1, 1), Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                       "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Score = c(2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1
                                                                                                                                                       )), .Names = c("status", "year", "Product", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           6L), class = "data.frame")

  x <- reactive({
    inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
    role <- as.double(input$role)
    range <- as.double(input$range)

    GapAnalysis_LongFormSat %>%
      filter(Product %in% inpt,
             status %in% role,
             year %in% range) %>%
      summarize(Avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      pull(-1)
  })


  y <- reactive({
    inpt <- as.double(input$inpt)
    role <- as.double(input$role)
    range <- as.double(input$range)

    GapAnalysis_LongFormImpt %>%
      filter(Product %in% inpt,
             status %in% role,
             year %in% range) %>% 
      summarize(Avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
      pull(-1)
  })

  xyCoords<- reactive({
    x <- x()
    y <- y()

    data.frame(col1=x, col2=y)})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    xyCoords <- xyCoords()

    xyCoords %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
      geom_point(colour ="green", shape = 17, size = 5 )+
      labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") +
      xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + 
      geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)})

}



shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you have some typos in your code and it should be `summarize(Avg =`. One `=`not two.

Comment: Thank you!! This only allows for plotting once all fields are populated, is there a way to have it plot for each breakdown/variable?

Comment: Made corrections to the original code...
As for plotting each variable/breakdown, with the code you have, I would suggest adding the default for everything to be selected using the `selected` argument in `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: @DaveGruenewald I'm now running into issues with color/shape coding everything... maybe you can help?? link to question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139261/ggplot-how-to-color-variables-that-have-parent-variables